# Add onclick at more then one object

Tags: android, layout

I create a button for each name in my database, then i should add at this button a onclick function, but i don't know what id use. i use ??? in the code for indicate the position

```
public class Game extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.game);

    ListView playersList=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.playersList);

    MyDb db=new MyDb(getApplicationContext());
    db.open();

    Cursor c=db.fetchAllUsers();
    startManagingCursor(c);

    SimpleCursorAdapter adapter=new SimpleCursorAdapter( 
            this,
            R.layout.user,
            c,
            new String[]{MyDb.UsersMetaData.USERS_NAME},
            new int[]{R.id.namePlayer}
    );

    playersList.setAdapter(adapter);
    db.close();

    Button newUser;
    newUser = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonNew);
    newUser.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            MyDb db=new MyDb(getApplicationContext());
            db.open();
            EditText inserted = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.editName);
            String nome = inserted.getText().toString();
            db.insertUser(nome);
            db.close();
        }
    });

    Button chosen;
    chosen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.???);
    chosen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Game2.class);
            startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
            finish();
        }
    });
    }

}
```

user interface

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/sfondo"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/sfondo">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">  

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"> 

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editName"
                android:text="@string/editName"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:lines="1"
                android:width="180px" />
        <Button
                android:text="@string/newPlayer"
                android:id="@+id/buttonNew"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:minWidth="70px" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/playersList"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />
    </LinearLayout>
</FrameLayout>
```

xml for the db elements

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
    >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/namePlayer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:minWidth="250px" />
</LinearLayout>
```

thanks

Comment: where `chosen = (Button)findViewById(R.id.???);` came from? In the layout I see just one `Button` element

Comment: i add other button in the java using he second xml

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So the button is in `R.layout.user`? If so I think you may need to extend `SimpleCursorAdapter` and in the `getView()` method you can find the view and add the listener. Something like this:

```
public class MyCursorAdapter extends SimpleCursorAdapter {
    public MyCursorAdapter(...) {
        super(...);
    }

    public void getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

        Button button = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.???);
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            public void onClick(View view) {
                ...
            }
        });
    }
}
```

That way your 'find' is scoped to one row in the list. You can't add the listener where you have the code currently because there will be multiple Views with the same ID.

Comment: can you exlain better whot should i modify?

Comment: In your code you instantiate a `SimpleCursorAdapter`. Instead of instantiating one of those you need to instantiate an extended version of it. Inside that extended version you need to extend `getView()` as above. This method is where the adapter inflates the second xml file in your question for every row and so is the most logical place to make any changes to the `View` such as adding a listener. I added to my answer to make the 'extension' clearer.

Comment: now i havi this:         
MyCursorAdapter adapter=new MyCursorAdapter(this,R.layout.user,c,new String[]{MyDb.UsersMetaData.USERS_NAME},new int[]{R.id.namePlayer});
adapter.getView(...); 
whot parameter i should put in the get View? i don't understand the documentation XD

Comment: You never need to call `getView(...)`, the framework will do it for you when it displays the list from the database. It was calling it before when you were using the `SimpleCursorAdapter` too, you just didn't realise it :)

Comment: i understand, another think, if i put: 
Intent myIntent = new Intent(view.getContext(), Game2.class);
startActivityForResult(myIntent, 0);
finish();
in the onClick say that i cannot use finish and start...result on the click listener becouse are undefined, i should call that on the activity right? how can i do?

Comment: i resolved with ((Activity) view.getContext()).finish(); thanks!
do you know why my text botton ary white when i use mycursoradapter and contain the right string when i use simplecursoradapeter?

Answer (score 1):

to define onClick to more than one object , your class should implement the interface `OnClickListener` , and override the method `onClick(View v)` , like this :

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstance){
....
//add listeners to your buttons 
btn1.setOnClikListener(this);
btn2.setOnClickListener(this);
....
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v ) {

if(v==btn1)
   // treatement 1 
if(v== btn2)
   //treatment 2 
...etc 
}
```